# Emmet multiple inline elements with break lines

Tags: html, emmet

Am trying to output 3 buttons(For example) with break lines between them

so when I type `button.btn*3`
the output looks like this

```
<button class="btn"></button><button class="btn"></button><button class="btn"></button>
```

How can I achieve an output like this for the **Inline elements** with **emmet** is that possible?

```
<button class="btn"></button>
<button class="btn"></button>
<button class="btn"></button>
```

Comment: You use `Alt + Shift + S` to format the code. It might be different in different IDEs.

Comment: @Amini it doesn't work in my case

Comment: Then you must install a code formatter like https://prettier.io/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for my question,

```
 "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {

        "html": {
            "inline_break": true,
        }
  }
```

this should be added to the settings.json file

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution using this in settings.json file

```
"emmet.preferences": {
    "output.inlineBreak": 1
}
```